# Nested If and map use in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my following code:-

```
if(this.props.buttons && this.props.buttons.tabs && this.props.buttons.tabs.length) {
            this.props.buttons.tabs.map((button) => {
                return (
                    <TabsPanel label={button.labelKey} />
                        button.subtabs.map((subtab) => {
                            return(
                                <Tabs>
                                    <TabsPanel label={subtab.labelKey}></TabsPanel>
                                </Tabs>
                            )
                        })
                )
            });
    }
```

While running this following code it's always giving Syntax Error.
[image]

Here's my following JSON which I am getting

```
    "tabs" : [ 
        {
            "labelKey" : "label1",
            "subtabs" : [ 
                {
                    "form" : {
                        "labelKey" : "subtab1"
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    "form" : {
                        "labelKey" : "subtab2"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "labelKey" : "label2"
        }
    ]
```

Any leads would be helpful. I am stuck at a dead end right now.
Thanks!

Comment: "While running this following code it's always giving Syntax Error" <- Please post the syntax error.

Comment: You have two consecutive `{`s after the `if`.

Comment: @CertainPerformance After removing that it's still not working.

Comment: @CertainPerformance please give us some time to solve the problem. You are solving everything very fast. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not very clear. But here are a few scenarios that I think could be intended.

1. TabsPanel component accepts Tabs as children:
   Answer by Prabin is as correct as it gets. (Except for missing key attributes in TabsPanel and Tabs components)
2. TabsPanel component and Tabs list go side by side:

Note: A valid component is either one single root, or it is a list of other valid components.

So either this is correct.

```
this.props.buttons.tabs.map((button, index) => {
    return (
      <div key={index}>
        <TabsPanel label={button.labelKey} />
        {button.subtabs.map(subtab => {
          return (
            <Tabs key={subtab.labelKey}>
              <TabsPanel label={subtab.labelKey} />
            </Tabs>
          )
        })}
      </div>
    )
  })
```

Or this is correct.

```
this.props.buttons.tabs.map((button, index) => {
  return [
    <TabsPanel label={button.labelKey} key={index} />,
    {
      ...button.subtabs.map(subtab => {
        return (
          <Tabs key={subtab.labelkey}>
            <TabsPanel label={subtab.labelKey} />
          </Tabs>
        )
      })
    }
  ]
})
```

Also, note the key attribute in Tabs and TabsPanel components. That is important and I leave it up to you to find it's importance.

Answer (score 0):

```
  return (
  <div>
    {this.props.buttons && this.props.buttons.tabs && this.props.buttons.tabs.length &&
      this.props.buttons.tabs.map(button => {
        return (
          <TabsPanel label={button.labelKey}>
            {button.subtabs.map(subtab => {
              return (
                <Tabs>
                  <TabsPanel label={subtab.labelKey} />
                </Tabs>
              );
            })}
          </TabsPanel>
        );
      })}
  </div>
);
```

Try this should solve your problem

Comment: The above solution isn't working.
tab.map wouldn't be working as the tab isn't defined. So, I changed it to this.props.buttons.tabs.map which also wasn't able to render anything. @prabin badyakar